# ImportError: No module named 'decouple' while deploying on Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, heroku-cli, python-decouple

I was trying to deploy my django project on heroku from heroku cli. So I created an app and then I ran `git push heroku master` from the project directory. Then I got the errors:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput 
remote:      Traceback (most recent call last): 
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module> 
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line 
remote:            utility.execute() 
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute 
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS 
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__ 
remote:            self._setup(name) 
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module) 
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__ 
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) 
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module 
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import 
remote: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load 
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in
_find_and_load_unlocked 
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked 
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module 
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed 
remote:          File "/tmp/build_93c58c906371cd0110470b6bb3ccecc1/funderpreneur/settings.py", line 15, in <module> 
remote:            from decouple import Csv, config 
remote:        ImportError: No module named 'decouple' 
remote:  
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'. 
remote:        See traceback above for details. 
remote:  
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error. 
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application: remote:  
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 
remote:  
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. 
remote:  
remote:  !     Push failed
```

So as it is mentioned, I ran `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`.
Then the codes were pushed in the repository. Then I ran `heroku run python3 manage.py migrate`. But still I got the same error saying:

> File "/app/funderpreneur/settings.py", line 15, in
>
> from decouple import Csv, config ImportError: No module named 'decouple'

But I have **python-decouple** installed locally for both python 2 and 3. And also the whole project is running on django version 2 and python version 3.5.2. But in the `runtime.txt` I have set `python-3.6.4`. I have `requirements.txt` where `decouple` is already there.

In my `settings.py` I had

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

But I was getting errors so I commented them. Still getting error.

What is wrong or what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

My `requirements.txt`:

```
dj-database-url
django
gunicorn
psycopg2
whitenoise
dj-static
Unipath
python-decouple
Pillow
Markdown
bleach
python-decouple
django-material
raven
django-debug-toolbar
django-tables2
django-phonenumber-field
django-guardian
django-notifications-hq
djangorestframework
matplotlib
numpy
seaborn
pandas
django-heroku
```

And the strucutre is:

```
.
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── footer.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── login.html
│   │       ├── navbar.html
│   │       ├── nav.html
│   │       ├── partial_settings_menu.html
│   │       ├── password.html
│   │       ├── picture.html
│   │       ├── profile.html
│   │       └── registration.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── funderpreneur
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── material-design-icons
│   │   │   ├── Material-Design-Iconsd41d.eot
│   │   │   ├── Material-Design-Icons.svg
│   │   │   ├── Material-Design-Icons.ttf
│   │   │   └── Material-Design-Icons.woff
│   │   └── roboto
│   │       ├── Roboto-Bold.ttf
│   │       ├── Roboto-Bold.woff
│   │       ├── Roboto-Light.ttf
│   │       ├── Roboto-Light.woff
│   │       ├── Roboto-Medium.ttf
│   │       ├── Roboto-Medium.woff
│   │       ├── Roboto-Regular.ttf
│   │       ├── Roboto-Regular.woff
│   │       ├── Roboto-Thin.ttf
│   │       └── Roboto-Thin.woff
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── account-settings.css
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   │   ├── custom-materialize.css
│   │   │   ├── footer.css
│   │   │   ├── high-rise-building.jpg
│   │   │   ├── materialize.css
│   │   │   ├── navbar.css
│   │   │   ├── navbar-top-fixed.css
│   │   │   ├── style2.css
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── humans.txt
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   └── buet_logo.png
│   │   └── js
│   │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │       ├── circular-progress-jquery.js
│   │       ├── jquery-1.11.2.min.js
│   │       ├── jquery-slim.min.js
│   │       ├── jquery.waypoints.min.js
│   │       ├── materialize.js
│   │       ├── popper.min.js
│   │       ├── profile-validation.js
│   │       └── registration-validation.js
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
├── Pipfile
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── staticfiles
```

Comment: Please show the actual requirements.txt, and the layout of your project.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you haven't written packages name from `requirements.txt` to the `Pipfile` bellow `[packages]` section. You should add packages in this format-

```
package_name = "version"
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP, can you please expand on this answer? Should be `[packages]` section contain all packages from `requirements.txt`? I tried including `python-decouple = "==3.1"` within `[packages]` to no avail. Currently, my `[packages]` contains only `django = "==2.1.2"`.

Answer (score 8):

I also had this problem, but by adding

`python-decouple==3.1`

into the `requirements.txt` file, I was able to get past it!

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the decouple module on your device. An event independent of the version change

try:

```
pip install python-decouple
```

no requirements.txt file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I'm new to django. The steps above didn't work after updating `requirements.txt` until I switched `env`.

```
source env/Scripts/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
py manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved by removing all package (removed 2x python-decouple from locally and decouple) from my env and locally. Then, I installed python-decouple (3.3) again.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error similar to this, turns out you have to install the module in the virtual environment. First, launch the virtual environment, then install the module(inside the virtual environment). Now try to launch your server, the problem should be solved
In some cases, there might be a module "decouple' installed, uninstall that module before launching your server as it will cause an error
[python](/questions/tagged/python) [python-decouple](/questions/tagged/python-decouple) [django](/questions/tagged/django)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because i had mistakenly `pip install decouple` instead of `pip install python-decouple`.

So just `pip uninstall decouple`
, and make sure the decouple package has been removed from either your `requirements.txt` or your `Pipfile/Pipfile.lock` files.

Then run `pip install python-decouple`