# Django internal server error - No module decouple

Tags: django, internal-server-error, linode

I am trying to deploy some basic django app on linode but I get error 500 whenever I try to access my website.

Requirement.txt installed using **venv** :

- asgiref==3.2.10
- certifi==2020.12.5
- chardet==4.0.0
- Django==3.1
- django-admin-honeypot==1.1.0
- django-admin-thumbnails==0.2.5
- django-session-timeout==0.1.0
- django-slugger==1.1.2 idna==2.10
- Pillow==8.2.0
- psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
- python-decouple==3.4
- pytz==2020.1
- requests==2.25.1
- six==1.15.0 sqlparse==0.3.1
- Unidecode==1.2.0
- urllib3==1.26.3

I have tried python-decouple==3.4, 3.3, 3.2, 3.1

Here are the files and logs

*tail -200 mysite-error.log*

```
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.788104 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733] mod_wsgi (pid=10477): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/GreatKart/greatkart/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.788180 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733] mod_wsgi (pid=10477): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/GreatKart/greatkart/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789344 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789422 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/var/www/GreatKart/greatkart/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789429 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789439 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789443 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789452 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789456 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789464 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789468 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     self._setup(name)
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789476 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789480 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789488 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789492 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789500 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789504 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789512 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789521 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789529 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789538 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789556 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789565 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789573 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]   File "/var/www/GreatKart/greatkart/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789577 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733]     from decouple import config
[Mon May 03 17:00:53.789596 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10477:tid 139635748644416] [remote 85.68.32.122:57733] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decouple'
```

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName lixxx-xxx.members.linode.com

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/greatkart-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/greatkart-access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess greatkart processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/GreatKart
WSGIProcessGroup greatkart
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/GreatKart/greatkart/wsgi.py

Alias /robots.txt /var/www/GreatKart/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/GreatKart/static/favicon.ico
Alias /static/ /var/www/GreatKart/static/
Alias /static/ /var/www/GreatKart/media/

<Directory /var/www/GreatKart/greatkart>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/GreatKart/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/GreatKart/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hello sir, seems that your problem is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541343/importerror-no-module-named-decouple-while-deploying-on-heroku

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

I do have a requirement.txt file that I've run through (venv) 

`Requirement already satisfied: python-decouple==3.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (3.4)`

Comment: The requirements.txt you posted is the one on your machine, or the one on your linode server.

Comment: It is the one on my linode server (which is the same as the one on my machine as I scp'd it